# pygame.FULLSCREEN Too large

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a fullscreen game and I am trying my best to make sure it fits all screen sizes. This proves quite difficult since when i use pygame.FULLSCREEN, the window is much larger than the screen. To solve this problem i have made the screen size 83% of what my screen size is according to python. It looks okay on my computer, but now if i use the same code on other computers and screens, the screen is too small.
This is the code:

```
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
print(infoObject)
w = int(infoObject.current_w*0.83)
h = int(infoObject.current_h*0.83)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

This creates a window that almost perfectly fits the screen, but i dont know why the fullscreen doesnt work by itself... Please help!

Full code:

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

def button(x,y,w,h,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        if click [0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "exit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
print(infoObject)
w = int(infoObject.current_w*0.83)
h = int(infoObject.current_h*0.83)
size = pygame.display.list_modes()[0]
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Turf War")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameExit = False
gameExit = False

box1X = 384
box1Y = 810
box2X = 1526
box2Y = 810
box3X = 384
box3Y = 260
box4X = 1526
box4Y = 260

box1 = pygame.Surface(((int(round(box1X*0.83))),(int(round(box1Y*0.83)))))
box1.set_alpha(220)
box1.fill((0,0,0))

box2 = pygame.Surface((((int(round(box2X*0.83)))-20(int(round(box2Y*0.83)))))
box2.set_alpha(220)
box2.fill((0,0,0))

box3 = pygame.Surface(((int(round(box3X*0.83))),((int(round(box3Y*0.83)))-20)))
box3.set_alpha(220)
box3.fill((0,0,0))

box4 = pygame.Surface((((int(round(box4X*0.83)))-20),((int(round(box4Y*0.83)))-20)))
box4.set_alpha(220)
box4.fill((0,0,0))

logo1 = pygame.image.load('logo.png')
logo2 = pygame.image.load('logo2.png')
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")

start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    time = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
    elapsed = time - start_time

    gameDisplay.fill(black)

    if elapsed > 4:
        gameDisplay.blit(bg,(0,0))
        button(0, 0, 10, 10, 'exit')
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (0, 0, 10, 10))
        gameDisplay.blit(box1, (10,10))
        gameDisplay.blit(box2, ((int(round(box1X*0.83)+20),10)))
        gameDisplay.blit(box3, (10,(h-(int(round(box3Y*0.83)))+10)))
        gameDisplay.blit(box4, ((int(round(box1X*0.83)+20),(h-(int(round(box3Y*0.83)))+10))))
    elif elapsed > 2:
        gameDisplay.blit(logo2, ((w*0.22), (h*0.4)))
    elif elapsed > 0:
        gameDisplay.blit(logo1, ((w*0.22), (h*0.3)))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

In case you are wondering, the if statements on the main loop are for a opening sequence of logos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the largest screen resolution first.
Use [`display.list_modes()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.list_modes) to get a list of available fullscreen modes. Pick the first as largest, because mode sizes are sorted from biggest to smallest:

```
largest_size = pygame.display.list_modes()[0]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(largest_size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: I tried that but it shifted everything on the page upwards and to the left. So I can see more of the bottom and right than i should, and i cant see a lot of the left and top of the page

Comment: I don't think the problem is with 'set_mode', the problem is probably in how you are rendering your data into the gameDisplay.  However, you really haven't given any code to review, so it is hard to tell or comment.

Comment: I'll edit and show the full code - its meant to be an interface with four boxes in the screen (starting 10 pixels from the top left of the screen and ending 10 pixels from the bottom right

Comment: This code doesn't run for me. Anyway, I"m basically confused. When in full-screen mode, you should have your "set_mode" set to the size of the screen. Period. You could alternatively set it to one of the other resolutions supported in the `list_modes()`, but I wouldn't recommend setting it arbitrary sizes like you are doing with this 0.83 thing. What do you mean when you do this "the window is much larger than the screen"? Since it is full-screen, what do you mean "window"?

Comment: Basically, i would like to make sure this works on all sizes and resolutions as possible. Sorry for the confusion, when i say window, i just mean the fullscreen application. Do you think i should have an option to change resolution/aspect ratio/ screen size on start up?

Comment: When i say the window is too big for the screen, i mean, when I open the game on fullscreen, i can only see part of of my fullscreen game window and the rest is out of the screen

Comment: Well you shouldn't need to do this 0.83 scaling in `set_mode`. If you aren't seeing all your content, you are drawing it off screen on accident I would suppose.

Comment: Its confusing me, because to make the box sizes, I used w-10 and h-10 coordinates for the bottom right corner- which should theoretically give me  a box that ends 10 pixels away from the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pygame.display.set_mode()` with the `(w, h)` values set to 0. From docs for [`set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode):

> If no size is passed or is set to `(0, 0)` and pygame uses `SDL` version 1.2.10 or above, the created Surface will have the same size as the **current screen resolution**. If only the width or height are set to `0`, the Surface will have the same width or height as the screen resolution. Using a `SDL` version prior to 1.2.10 will raise an exception.

That will avoid any weird zooming or shifting.

Example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```